# Suppress anonymous structs warning with Clang - "-fms-extensions" doesn't work

Tags: visual-c++, clang, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, compiler-flags

I have an Xcode project that I compile with Clang using some 3rd party library with Visual Studio C code.

In the 3rd party library anonymous structs are used in header files (I can't really change that). Thus I get this warning:

"myfile.h:47:17: Anonymous structs are a GNU extension"

As described here, I tried to pass "-fms-extensions" in the C flags of my Xcode project:
http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#microsoft-extensions

No luck. Any idea how to get rid of that warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `-Wno-microsoft` did not work for me.

Using this small test program

```
typedef struct test_struct
{
  struct
  {
    int a;
    int b;
  };
  int x;
} Test;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Test test;
  test.a = 0;
}
```

using `-Wno-gnu` disables the warning

Version is Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `-Wno-microsoft` to hide the warning.